# Need help plotting on Mathematica simple piecewise wave function from quantum physics (Quantum Physics, Griffiths, 2.7)

Tags: plotting, functions, piecewise, plot-themes, recreational-mathematics

On Mathematica need to plot an initial wave function defined as...

Psi(x,0) = Ax when 0 <= x <= a/2

Psi(x,0) = A(a - x) when a/2 <= x <= a

Here is my attempted code...

```
Clear["Global`*"]
psi1 := x
psi2 := (a - x)
Plot[Piecewise[{{psi1, {x, x < a/2}}, {psi2, {x, x > a/2}}}], {x, 0, a}]
```

Please help me fix this. Also please feel free to add fancy styling or formatting as I also want to learn how to edit charts for showing axis labels, legends, color, etc.

Comment: You never give a numerical value for `a`. If you do so it should plot cleanly.